# mysql - unable to call stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure with the Add Routine method in phpMyAdmin and when I try to execute the stored procedure I get this :

[image]

I'm testing stored procedures out and it's literally a `select * from tableName` which obviously runs through normal SQL.

Thank you

Comment: Please add the code you are using to call it.

Comment: "MySQL said" what? Surely phpmyadmin has a way of returning the error message. If you run it with another MySQL client, you should see more of an error message. A shot in the dark thing that could go wrong, for example, is a lack of the `EXECUTE` permission for the user logged into the database.  It is also possible that an error in the SP definition allows it to  be created but fails at runtime. Please post the full `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: @Techidiot the code used to call it is in the picture i posted...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `CREATE PROCEDURE  ``spDulce`` ( ) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER SELECT * 
FROM Dulce`. It's not a permissions issue because I'm using sa.

Comment: I'm creating and executing this procedure using phpmyadmins designer I'm sure it wouldn't be a case of incorrect syntax would it?

Comment: Does it really result in double backticks like `\`\`spDulce\`\`` ? That would point to something going wrong in the creation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski no I'm sorry i only did that so the whole link would show as code. Thank you for your help man

Comment: Oh ok. You can backslash-escape backticks in comments here so they print as literals.

Comment: Unless you can get phpmyadmin to print the actual error, it's going to be very hard to sort this out. Can you connect to this database with a different client like the command-line `mysql` (using the same user/password as PMA)? Then a simple `CALL spDolce()` should print more info.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i just used xampp to connect to my rds through the localhost environment and it works perfectly... seems like maybe the installation of phpmyadmin on my aws ec2 server may be bad?